Use Azure Devops REST API to get YAML defintion of Release (steps)
A classical build pipeline in Azure Devops can be exported to YAML, following the documentation of the REST API I use
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/yaml?api-version=7.2-preview.1

I'm stuck doing the same thing for a classic Release; through the Azure Devops user interface, when I edit a classic Release, I can for each individual step press a button that will show me the YAML definition. Is there an automated way to do this (using Powershell)?
